# Use different sender emails

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I am struggling with an email address that is used to send all emails. I am using a function in function.php to overwrite wp default email.

```
function wpb_sender_email( $original_email_address ) {
    return 'admin@test.com';
}
```

It seems that this function is causing a lot of trouble as all emails that go from the server, admin@test.com is a sender.

I am using elementor and contact-7 forms, is there a way when I set in form "From" field email that is using that email not admin@test.com

Comment: In contact form 7 form settings, you can define the sender mail adress in the tab "e-mail". But you do not want to use what you have defined, but instead another mail adress? Please be more clear about what you want to achieve.

Comment: I used the above function to overwrite wordpres@ email which is the default. I think I was clear as I said I want to use the email that is set in form in FROM field. That will be different through the forms.

Comment: Yeah well, I still don't get it. But it is your choice if you want it to make more clear or not. I cannot help you without more clearity. Happy coding!